# Java String search and replace

Tags: java, strings, search

I would like to search a `String`, and for a certain word, I would like to change only the first 3 letters

For example:

> This is a java institute which insures that you are in that institute. ins!

I want to change the first 3 letter of institute (ins) to JSE, so the result will be:

> This is a java JSEtitute which insures that you are in that JSEtitute. ins!

I have the following, but it is NOT doing the job perfectly:

```
public class ExistanceAndReplace {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String s = "This is a java institute of insurance and insu.";

if (s.contains("institute")) {
    String s1 = s.replaceFirst("ins", "JSS");
    System.out.println(s1);


}else{
    System.out.println("not found!");
}

}

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code of yours is not working, despite your assurances that it is. It replaces just the first occurrence of 'ins', and that should be obvious since you call the `replaceFirst` method. The example sentence you use in the code is not the same as the sentence in your description. The one in the description will fail your code:

> ```
> This is a java institute which insures that you are in that institute. ins!
> ```

Your code will produce:

> ```
> This is a java JSStitute which insures that you are in that institute. ins!
> ```

and it should produce:

> ```
> This is a java JSEtitute which insures that you are in that JSEtitute. ins!
> ```

There are three problems

1. the specification says replace the `ins` in `institute` with `JSE`, your code though, replaces just the first `ins` in `institute`, not them all
2. you replace the `ins` with `JSS`, and not `JSE`.
3. you don't check for the beginning of the word... you will find `ins` in "dustbins".

These small details are things you have to fix, and show a low attention to detail.

Of course, a more advanced solution would be:

```
s.replaceAll("\\bins(?=titute\\b)", "JSE");
```

You can see that in action [here in **Ideone**](http://ideone.com/vvVLWA)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much that really helped. Also sorry for the typo I will just change it right now, I meant to say "it is NOT doing the job perfectly".

Comment: @newmudhar for future reference, broken code is off topic on Code Review and will likely be put on hold. If you need help making code work correctly, use Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

- Everything inside curly braces should be indented by the same number of spaces, even within the outer class.  In Java, it's usually four.  You've already done it correctly with the conditionals, so have it done everywhere else.
- `s` should be `final` as it's not meant to be modified.  You should also give it a better name that describes its meaning.  SIngle-character variable names are discouraged with the exception of `for` loop counter variables.

  ```
  final String originalString = "This is a java institute of insurance and insu.";
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `contains()` check. Just remove the `if-else` statement:

```
public class ExistanceAndReplace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "This is a java institute of insurance and insu.";
        String s1 = s.replaceFirst("ins", "JSS");
        System.out.println(s1);
    }

}
```

Also, you could just print the result immediately:

```
public class ExistanceAndReplace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "This is a java institute of insurance and insu.";
        System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("ins", "JSS"));
    }

}
```

Not really much of else to say, since it is a short program.

Answer (score 1):

My weakness is the RegEx, so I kept trying and reached the below:

```
private static void replaceChars(String str, String toReplace, String replaceWith) {
    str = str.replaceAll(toReplace, replaceWith + toReplace.subSequence(3, toReplace.length()));
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

It is a method which makes it even dynamic.

Comment: I don't like how it prints the result instead of returning it. Try: `private static String replaceChars(...) {...return str;}` where `str` is what you have here.